# Disadvantages of not specifying SqlDbType in SqlCommand.Parameter

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm implementing some connected ADO.NET functions (no EF, no Linq, no datasets). I've built a set of routines that

1) take an instantiated class object corresponding to a table row ("row object"),

2) use Refection to extract the property types, names and values from the row object and store them in a List,

3) use the List to turn those names into a SQL query string using @Value type parameters,

4) use the List to load row object property values into the SQLCommand.Parameters
    corresponding to the @Values. 
 The purpose of this general approach to be able to use this approach with multiple row object types and not have to create separate insert, update and delete SQLCommand routines for each row object type.  In the initial test run, this works fine.

Question:  what are potential problems or disadvantages that I might run into by not including the SqlDbType in the SQLCommand.Parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always avoid usage of SqlParameter that do not specify SqlDbType, unless you are sure that you will set the type later.

Please read [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2008/10/29/why-you-should-always-specify-the-sqldbtype-for-an-ado.net.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. So, gotta do it.  And, BTW, doh, try to do this all with stored procedures.

Comment: The link is broken.